# Searching the smaller picture in the larger picture

Tags: c#

Searching the smaller picture in the larger picture I’m looking for a C# source code by which I can give a small picture as the input. Provided that the picture is in the larger picture, the program will give the coordinates of the smaller picture as the output!

I want the code search the larger image, not search for similarities of the pixels one by one.

I tried to do that, but I couldn't. As I mentioned, I’m looking for a C# source code.

Comment: Did you want C# or python code

Comment: Yes, please ask for C# or Python, not both

Comment: I want C# code  if can

Comment: It's fine to ask for both Python and C#. But you should tag your question better as there's no tag related to images. Also, what does "I want the code search the larger image, not search for similarities of the pixels one by one" mean exactly? That sentence doesn't quite make sense. It sounds as if you wanted to search the large picture without knowing the pixels of the smaller one.

Comment: Did you try [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php)?